# Silverlight: Print XPS Programmatically

Tags: silverlight, printing, xps

Is there any way (library or native) to use the printing API to print an XPS document? I tried using the [Document Toolkit API](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/documenttoolkit/) which works up to a point, but I get a COM exception when I try to set `PrintPageEventArgs.PageVisual`.

Comment: What have Firstfloorsoftware said about it when you asked them?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones Exception was a problem on my end. They said the next release will bring official support for Silverlight 4 and printing. It will also provide a workaround for the PathGeometry Figure attributes generated by the XPS printer driver which are not compatible with Silverlight (another issue I ran into). So I'm holding out for the next release.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it in native code, don't forget to enable COM first:

```
    SmartHandle event = ::CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (event.get() == 0)
    {
        ::AtlThrow(::GetLastError());
    }

    CComPtr<IXpsOMObjectFactory> pXpsFactory;
    HRESULT hr = pXpsFactory.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_XpsOMObjectFactory);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        ::AtlThrow(hr);
    }

    CComPtr<IXpsPrintJobStream> pDocumentStream;
    hr = ::StartXpsPrintJob(printer, file, NULL, NULL, event.get(), NULL, NULL, NULL, &pDocumentStream, NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        ::AtlThrow(hr);
    }

    CComPtr<IXpsOMPackage> pXpsOMPackage;

    hr = pXpsFactory->CreatePackageFromFile(argv[2], false, &pXpsOMPackage);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        ::AtlThrow(hr);
    }

    hr = pXpsOMPackage->WriteToStream(pDocumentStream, FALSE);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        ::AtlThrow(hr);
    }

    pDocumentStream->Close();

    if (::WaitForSingleObject(event.get(), INFINITE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {
        ::AtlThrow(hr);
    }
```